# how to find location of missing library

Tags: c++, mysql

I have installed the mysql connector for c++.  I am writing a c++ cgi app.  The cgi page has been compiling.  I rebooted yesterday and it stopped compiling.  `g++ -o sales.cgi sales.cpp -lcgicc -lmysqlcppcon`. Gives the following error.  `/usr/bin/ld cannot find -lmysqlcppcon`
apt-get tells me I have the latest version of libmysqlcppconn7v5 and i have the latest version of libmyqlcppconn-dev.  How do I find the library.  I checked `/usr/lib/` but I have no idea what I should be looking for.

Comment: The libmysqlcppcon-dev package [installs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libmysqlcppconn-dev/filelist) a `libmysqlcppcon.so` which is linked as -lmysqlcppcon. If that "stopped compiling", you accidentally removed that file or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you installed with [apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get), then you can use [dpkg](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg) to determine which files were installed.

EXAMPLE (you would substitute "mysqlcppcon"):

```
dpkg -l|grep -i mysql
ii  php-mysql                        1:7.2+60ubuntu1                            all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
...  <= Search for the exact package name (here, "php-mysql")

   dpkg -L php-mysql
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/php-mysql
/usr/share/doc/php-mysql/copyright
/usr/share/doc/php-mysql/changelog.gz
  <= List files installed to your system from that package
```

You can also use [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

EXAMPLE:

```
find / -name "*mysqlcppcon*" -print 2> /dev/null
```

The `*xxx*` syntax let's you do a wildcard search;  `2> /dev/null` filters out irrelevant"noise" from your wildcard search, like "find: ‘/run/lvm’: Permission denied".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the help.  Huge typo on my side.  I needed `g++ -o sales.cgi sales.cpp -lcgicc -lmysqlcppconn`